# Multiple object sets per type are not supported when i create a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

when i create a dropdown list in identity tabel `AspNetRole` with this code

IdentityConfig.cs

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

.

```
.private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
{
    get
    {
        return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _roleManager = value;
    }
}
```

controller :

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.name = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName");

        return View();
    }
```

View :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>نقش</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("name", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

it show me this error :

[image]

How can i solve that ?

/************************************************************************************************/

Comment: show me this error : `DataBinding: 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IdentityRole_9C239D4C47FAFC45E921B1820B5C41AF0EB067AE64D4B8640EE82A0D5F0D4504' does not contain a property with the name 'RoleID'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register() {
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

    return View();
}
```

OR

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register() {
    var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new { RoleID = r.Id, RoleName = r.Name}).ToList();
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "RoleID", "RoleName");

    return View();
}
```

View :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>نقش</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("SelectedRole", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are my herrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrro . thank you agin :))))

Answer (score 2):

try with this code, **changes**

```
ViewBag.name = new SelectList(db.Roles.ToList(), "RoleID", "RoleName");
```

and your dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownList("name", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: show me this error :`DataBinding: 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IdentityRole_9C239D4C47FA‌​FC45E921B1820B5C41AF‌​0EB067AE64D4B8640EE8‌​2A0D5F0D4504' does not contain a property with the name 'RoleID'.`

Comment: I think, In AspNetRole table contain two column like Id,Name